# Contar filas en una consulta que une dos tablas en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi BD MYSQL

Tabla **venta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla **detalle_venta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es obtener la cantidad de ventas y el total de ventas que hubó en un cierto día de un mes, tengo la siguiente consulta MySql pero no funciona correctamente en cuanto al conteo de ventas:

```
SELECT DAY(fecha) AS dia, SUM(importe) AS total, COUNT(folio) AS ventas FROM venta 
INNER JOIN detalle_venta ON venta.id_venta = detalle_venta.id_venta 
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 1 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2024 GROUP BY dia
```

Por ejemplo:

En el mes **1** del año **2024** espero el siguiente resultado:

```
Dia    Total   Ventas
 4     171.95   5
 5     38       1
```

Pero la consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Dia    Total   Ventas
 4     171.95   12
 5     38       2
```

Me doy cuenta que este resultado erroneo lo devuelve por el **INNER JOIN** que une a ambas tablas pero entonces como puedo resolver esto??

Comment: Saludos. Tu tabla venta deberia tener una columna id_detalle_venta como clave primaria y id_venta como clave foranea para que asi puedas relacionarlas y saber que detalle pertenece a que venta. Tambien me surge la duda, porque consultas la fecha por partes si la tienes registrada en una sola columna y puedes hacer un where fecha = fechaRecibidaPorParametros.

Comment: ¿Será con `count(distinct folio)`?

Comment: @Sal efectivamente esa fue la solución, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @ErnestoRincon la consulta de fecha la separo porque necesito obtener solo los registros de un cierto mes y año. En realidad es necesario añadir en la tabla detalle_venta ese campo que dices como clave primaria??

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar duplicados en la suma de la cuenta de ventas podrías utilizar una sub consulta para calcular el total de ventas por día antes de hacer el JOIN de las tablas.

Aquí el codigo:

```sql
SELECT DAY(fecha) AS dia, 
       SUM(importe) AS total, 
       COUNT(venta.id_venta) AS ventas 
FROM venta 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_venta, SUM(importe) AS importe
    FROM detalle_venta
    GROUP BY id_venta
) detalle_venta ON venta.id_venta = detalle_venta.id_venta
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 1 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2024 
GROUP BY dia;
```

La sub consulta agrupa  detalle_venta por el id_venta y calcula la suma del importe para cada una, luego la consulta principal hace el JOIN con venta y la sub consulta, evitando así el duplicado.